# How to generate in Javascript all combinations of items from multiple objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion, combinations, cartesian-product

I have an array of objects with names and options and I need all possible combinations of products. The important part is that this array has an N number of objects with N number of options in every object.

I tried to create some kind of recursive algorithm, but the problem is that I failed to push recursively to receive the needed data structure in the end. I also tried the approach from [Cartesian product of multiple arrays in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12303989/cartesian-product-of-multiple-arrays-in-javascript) but it seems it is not relevant to the output needed.

Example:

```
input = [
    {
        name: "Size",
        options: [ { value: "S" }, { value: "M" }, { value: "L" }, ...and so on]
    },
    {
        name: "Color",
        options: [ { value: "Red" }, { value: "White" }, { value: "Blue" }, ...and so on]
    },
    {
        name: "Weight",
        options: [ { value: "1kg" }, { value: "2kg" }, { value: "3kg" }, { value: "4kg"}, ]
    },
    .... and so on
];
```

I need to have all the possible combinations in the form of the array which itself includes an array of objects with the object's name and value.

Example (Array of arrays):

```
    output = [ 
    [ {name: 'Size', value: 'S'}, {name: 'Color', value: 'Red'}, {name: 'Weight', value: '1kg'} ],
    [ {name: 'Size', value: 'S'}, {name: 'Color', value: 'Red'}, {name: 'Weight', value: '2kg'} ],
    [ {name: 'Size', value: 'S'}, {name: 'Color', value: 'Red'}, {name: 'Weight', value: '3kg'} ],
    [ {name: 'Size', value: 'S'}, {name: 'Color', value: 'Red'}, {name: 'Weight', value: '4kg'} ],
    [ {name: 'Size', value: 'S'}, {name: 'Color', value: 'White'}, {name: 'Weight', value: '1kg'} ],
    [ {name: 'Size', value: 'S'}, {name: 'Color', value: 'White'}, {name: 'Weight', value: '2kg'} ],
    [ {name: 'Size', value: 'S'}, {name: 'Color', value: 'White'}, {name: 'Weight', value: '3kg'} ],
    [ {name: 'Size', value: 'S'}, {name: 'Color', value: 'White'}, {name: 'Weight', value: '4kg'} ],
    [ {name: 'Size', value: 'S'}, {name: 'Color', value: 'Blue'}, {name: 'Weight', value: '1kg'} ],
    [ {name: 'Size', value: 'S'}, {name: 'Color', value: 'Blue'}, {name: 'Weight', value: '2kg'} ],
    [ {name: 'Size', value: 'S'}, {name: 'Color', value: 'Blue'}, {name: 'Weight', value: '3kg'} ],
    [ {name: 'Size', value: 'S'}, {name: 'Color', value: 'Blue'}, {name: 'Weight', value: '4kg'} ],
    [ {name: 'Size', value: 'M'}, {name: 'Color', value: 'Red'}, {name: 'Weight', value: '1kg'} ],
    [ {name: 'Size', value: 'M'}, {name: 'Color', value: 'Red'}, {name: 'Weight', value: '2kg'} ],
    [ {name: 'Size', value: 'M'}, {name: 'Color', value: 'Red'}, {name: 'Weight', value: '3kg'} ],
    [ {name: 'Size', value: 'M'}, {name: 'Color', value: 'Red'}, {name: 'Weight', value: '4kg'} ],
    [ {name: 'Size', value: 'M'}, {name: 'Color', value: 'White'}, {name: 'Weight', value: '1kg'} ],
    [ {name: 'Size', value: 'M'}, {name: 'Color', value: 'White'}, {name: 'Weight', value: '2kg'} ],
    [ {name: 'Size', value: 'M'}, {name: 'Color', value: 'White'}, {name: 'Weight', value: '3kg'} ],
    [ {name: 'Size', value: 'M'}, {name: 'Color', value: 'White'}, {name: 'Weight', value: '4kg'} ],
    ... and so on 
];
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cartesian product of multiple arrays in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12303989/cartesian-product-of-multiple-arrays-in-javascript)

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Please take the [tour], visit the [help] and read up on [asking good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). After doing some research and [searching](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) for related topics on SO, try it yourself. If you're stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt and note exactly where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: @pilchard, unfortunately not, I need to implement the solution for an array of objects and I need to preserve both values from the object in the output, as in the example.

Comment: regardless of the contents of the array the method is the same.

Comment: @pilchard how can the method from [Cartesian product of multiple arrays in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12303989/cartesian-product-of-multiple-arrays-in-javascript) be implemented in my case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**: Fixed the first `cartesian` implementation based on suggestion from Mulan.

This is definitely a cartesian product question.  The only thing is that you will need to format your input before you call the cartesian product.  Here is one version, using a simple, recursive `cartesian` function.

```js
const cartesian = ([xs, ...xss]) =>
  xs == undefined
    ? [[]]
  : xs .flatMap (x => cartesian (xss) .map (ys => [x, ...ys]))

const combine = (properties) =>
  cartesian (properties .map (({name, options}) => options .map (({value}) => ({name, value}))))

const properties = [{name: "Size", options: [ { value: "S" }, { value: "M" }, { value: "L" }, /*...and so on */]}, {name: "Color", options: [ { value: "Red" }, { value: "White" }, { value: "Blue" }, /*...and so on */]}, {name: "Weight", options: [ { value: "1kg" }, { value: "2kg" }, { value: "3kg" }, { value: "4kg"}, ]}, /* .... and so on */]

console .log (JSON .stringify (combine (properties), null, 2))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

But I find your output format quite repetitive.  I would prefer something like:

```js
[
  {Size: "S", Color: "Red", Weight: "1kg"},
  {Size: "S", Color: "Red", Weight: "2kg"},
  {Size: "S", Color: "Red", Weight: "3kg"},
  {Size: "S", Color: "Red", Weight: "4kg"},
  {Size: "S", Color: "White", Weight: "1kg"},
  // ...
  {Size: "L", Color: "Blue", Weight: "4kg"},
]
```

and we can achieve it with just a bit more work:

```js
const cartesian = ([xs, ...xss]) =>
  xs == undefined
    ? [[]]
  : xs .flatMap (x => cartesian (xss) .map (ys => [x, ...ys]))


const combine = (properties) =>
  cartesian (properties .map (
    ({name, options}) => options .map (({value}) => ({[name]: value}))
  )) .map (ps => Object .assign ({}, ...ps))

const properties = [{name: "Size", options: [ { value: "S" }, { value: "M" }, { value: "L" }, /*...and so on */]}, {name: "Color", options: [ { value: "Red" }, { value: "White" }, { value: "Blue" }, /*...and so on */]}, {name: "Weight", options: [ { value: "1kg" }, { value: "2kg" }, { value: "3kg" }, { value: "4kg"}, ]}, /* .... and so on */]

console .log (combine (properties))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

If that version of the cartesian product does not make sense to you, this one is an alternative:

```js
const cartesian = ([x, ...xs]) => 
  (xs || []) .reduce (
    (a, b) => a .reduce (
      (c, d) => [... c, ... (b .map (e => [... d, e]))],
      []
    ),
    (x || []) .map (x => [x])
  )
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This is exactly the solution I was looking for but was stuck on the recursion step. The solution is extremely compact and efficient

Comment: assignment of `xs = undefined` looks like a potential mistake

Comment: unless i am overlooking something, i think i found a way around the `length` check. i would've included as an edit but unsure if you feel it would clash with your post. supplemental answer provided.

Comment: @Mulan: Not only is it a typo, but it's an entirely unnecessary check as your own answer shows!  I will update, but please, always feel free to edit my answers.

Answer (score 1):

This is only a supplement to @Scott's already terrific answer. I wanted to offer two alternatives for `cartesian` -

```js
const cartesian = ([t, ...more]) =>
  t == null
    ? [[]]
    : t.flatMap(v => cartesian(more).map(r => [v, ...r]))
```

Using Scott's `combine` function -

```js
for (const c of combine(properties))
  console.log(c)
```

```js
{"Size":"S","Color":"Red","Weight":"1kg"}
{"Size":"S","Color":"Red","Weight":"2kg"}
{"Size":"S","Color":"Red","Weight":"3kg"}
{"Size":"S","Color":"Red","Weight":"4kg"}
{"Size":"S","Color":"White","Weight":"1kg"}
{"Size":"S","Color":"White","Weight":"2kg"}
{"Size":"S","Color":"White","Weight":"3kg"}
{"Size":"S","Color":"White","Weight":"4kg"}
{"Size":"S","Color":"Blue","Weight":"1kg"}
{"Size":"S","Color":"Blue","Weight":"2kg"}
{"Size":"S","Color":"Blue","Weight":"3kg"}
{"Size":"S","Color":"Blue","Weight":"4kg"}
{"Size":"M","Color":"Red","Weight":"1kg"}
{"Size":"M","Color":"Red","Weight":"2kg"}
{"Size":"M","Color":"Red","Weight":"3kg"}
{"Size":"M","Color":"Red","Weight":"4kg"}
{"Size":"M","Color":"White","Weight":"1kg"}
{"Size":"M","Color":"White","Weight":"2kg"}
{"Size":"M","Color":"White","Weight":"3kg"}
{"Size":"M","Color":"White","Weight":"4kg"}
{"Size":"M","Color":"Blue","Weight":"1kg"}
{"Size":"M","Color":"Blue","Weight":"2kg"}
{"Size":"M","Color":"Blue","Weight":"3kg"}
{"Size":"M","Color":"Blue","Weight":"4kg"}
{"Size":"L","Color":"Red","Weight":"1kg"}
{"Size":"L","Color":"Red","Weight":"2kg"}
{"Size":"L","Color":"Red","Weight":"3kg"}
{"Size":"L","Color":"Red","Weight":"4kg"}
{"Size":"L","Color":"White","Weight":"1kg"}
{"Size":"L","Color":"White","Weight":"2kg"}
{"Size":"L","Color":"White","Weight":"3kg"}
{"Size":"L","Color":"White","Weight":"4kg"}
{"Size":"L","Color":"Blue","Weight":"1kg"}
{"Size":"L","Color":"Blue","Weight":"2kg"}
{"Size":"L","Color":"Blue","Weight":"3kg"}
{"Size":"L","Color":"Blue","Weight":"4kg"}
```

Another approach to `cartesian` might look like this. Generators are always a great fit for problems involving combinations and permutations -

```js
function* cartesian([t, ...more]) {
  if (t == null)
    return yield []
  for (const v of t)
    for (const c of cartesian(more))
      yield [v, ...c]
}

function* combine(t) {
  for (const ps of cartesian(t.map(({name, options}) => options.map(({value}) => ({[name]: value})))))
    yield Object.assign({}, ...ps)
}
```

```js
for (const c of combine(properties))
  console.log(c)
```

Output is identical -

```js
{"Size":"S","Color":"Red","Weight":"1kg"}
{"Size":"S","Color":"Red","Weight":"2kg"}
{"Size":"S","Color":"Red","Weight":"3kg"}
...
{"Size":"L","Color":"Blue","Weight":"2kg"}
{"Size":"L","Color":"Blue","Weight":"3kg"}
{"Size":"L","Color":"Blue","Weight":"4kg"}
```

Use [Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) if you would like to collect the results in an array.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Generators approach also looks really great.